Rateslib - Pricing 1y EUR vs 6M (EUSA01)
I am using the rateslib python library to try to price some European swaps. It seems to be working for most tenors aside from the 1y for some reason.
The code I am using is below:
from rateslib import *
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
import pandas as pd


today = dt.today()
start = add_tenor(today,"2b","F",get_calendar("tgt"))
maturity = add_tenor(start,"1Y","F",get_calendar("tgt"))

eurcurve = '45'


eurcurve_id = 'YCSW' + eurcurve.zfill(4) + ' Index'
eurresp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data(eurcurve_id,'CURVE_TENOR_RATES')
eurdf = eurresp.as_frame()
eurtenors = eurdf['CURVE_TENOR_RATES'].iloc[0]['Tenor'].to_list()
eurrates = eurdf['CURVE_TENOR_RATES'].iloc[0]['Mid Yield'].to_list()

eurdata = pd.DataFrame({"Term": eurtenors, 
                        "Rate":eurrates})

eurdata["Termination"] = [add_tenor(start,_,"F","tgt") for _ in eurdata["Term"]]

eureur = Curve(
    id = "eureur",
    convention=defaults.spec["eur_irs"]["convention"],
    calendar=defaults.spec["eur_irs"]["calendar"],
    modifier=defaults.spec["eur_irs"]["modifier"],
    interpolation="log_linear",
    nodes={
        **{today:1.0},
        **{_:1.0 for _ in eurdata["Termination"]},
    }
)
        

eur_kws = dict(
    spec="eur_irs",
    effective = start,
    curves ="eureur"
)


eursolver = Solver(
    curves=[eureur],
    instruments=[IRS(termination=_,**eur_kws)for _ in eurdata["Termination"]],
    s = eurdata["Rate"],
    instrument_labels=eurdata["Term"],
    id = "eur_rates"
)


eurdata["DF"] = [float(eureur[_]) for _ in eurdata["Termination"]]

eurirs = IRS(
    notional = -10e6,
    termination = maturity,
    **eur_kws
)


eurswaprate = eurirs.rate(solver=eursolver)

print(eurswaprate)
print(eurdata)

so the output from this code, looking at the rates and the discount factors vs bbg, look fine to me
Here are the BBG values

and here are the ones in 'eurdata' from my code

so these have a slightly bigger margin of error than i see in the sofr curve example in the rateslib docs but i think this is because the rates that i pull from bbg dont match exactly what the 'curves' tab in SWPM has.
Anyway, when i then print the rate out on this 1y swap i get some pretty different values.
BBG = 3.68
Me = 3.451


I thought this was just something i was doing wrong (and it likely still is). However what i found that was weird is that it seems to match much much closer (within a bp) when looking at essentially any other tenor. for example the 2y and 5y below
2y BBG = 3.4185
2y Me = 3.418
5y BBG = 3.03145
5y Me = 3.032




So my question is:
Is there something fundamentally incorrect with how I am either using the rateslib library or how i am approaching this problem? I have done my best to try and piece together from the docs but struggling to get there

in EUR curves are usually created in a multi-curve environment. I.e. they usually use ESTR for discounting. In USD the SOFR curve serves as forecast and discount curve, which is why it will match better. Additionally you are using the spec "eur_irs", which is for ESTR swaps. To do this properly you should use spec as "eur_irs6" and you should create a second curve which is the ESTR curve and is calibrated by ESTR swaps (or 6m ESTR basis swaps). The Instrument specification is important and small mismatches can produce big pricing differences.

ahh ok thanks! So I would just pass 2 curves into the solver in this case, one being my forecasting curve (current curve above) and then the second curve would be the discount curve which i could either just create by pulling the ESTR swaps or use the basis.
Question on the basis, how does rateslib know when im passing in a spread rather than a rate when caibrating the curve? is it because the basis swap would be an SBS rather than an IRS and it just knows?

Technically, for EUR swaps you should actually use a Spread of two IRSs (an ESTR and a 6m euribor) which is the quoted price on screens (this is the difference between the two fixed rates). You can use a basis swap, SBS but then the price you would see on screens is not exactly the same. But provided for every Instrument you specify the curves of every leg the solver will calibrate it all correctly. For your purposes it is probably easier to just calibrate an ESTR curve with ESTR swaps and 6M euribor curve using 6M swaps and the ESTR curve you have created.

Legend, thanks.

By the way, see here -> https://github.com/attack68/rateslib/issues/108 where someone else was doing a similar thing.

@Attack68 unrelated but didnt want to start a new question thread. Will default specs for AUD/NZD ever be added to the lib?

Post an issue on the project. If the specs are given they are easy to add. They are much harder to self research and validate.
